# Ajax properties in draggable table not being rendered with drupal_render, need workaround

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I'm building a form where part of it is a draggable table. The table consists of rows with a picture in one cell and a delete button on another. Basically a user can click the delete button on each row and an ajax call will delete that specific row.

This is the code for the table:

```
$header = array(
    t('Image'),
    t('Operations'),
    t('Weight'),         
);    

$form['images'] = array(
    '#tree' => TRUE,    
    '#prefix' => '<div id="image-fieldset-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',    
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => $header,         
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'images-table'),
);

foreach ($image_array as $fid => $uri) {

  $image_data = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'object_image_preview', 'path' => $uri)),
  );

  $button_data = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Delete'),      
      '#submit' => array('ajax_callback_remove'),
      '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
          'wrapper' => 'image-fieldset-wrapper',
      ),
  );

  $weight_data = array(
      '#type' => 'weight',
      '#title' => t('Weight'),
      '#delta' => 10,
      '#title-display' => 'invisible',
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('images-weight')),
  );

  $form['images']['#rows'][] = array(
      'data' => array(
          drupal_render($image_data), 
          drupal_render($button_data), 
          drupal_render($weight_data),
          ),
      'class' => array('draggable'),            
  );

}

drupal_add_tabledrag('images-table', 'order', 'sibling', 'images-weight');

return $form;
```

The code creates the draggable table with the images and the buttons but i'm running into  drupal_render not rendering the ajax properties of the button.
This has also been discussed here [Drupal 7 API/drupal_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7)

Despite that discussion I haven't been able to find a solution that applies to my code. I've tried rendering the data this way:

```
drupal_render_children(drupal_get_form('object_image_create_data', $vars)
```

where object_image_create_data() returns the same data and it works in rendering the ajax properties correctly, but with this I'm getting an error

> Notice: Undefined index: callback in ajax_form_callback()

Also, I'm not able to get to the $form_state of the original form to make the changes so that when the form is rebuild the clicked row is removed

Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.